# Vue.js component with Vuex.js (instead of vue-i18n.js)

Tags: javascript, internationalization, vue.js

I've been trying to reproduce the button behavior that I've [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/2L6sLx3g/4/), but with a different implementation. Basically, I'm trying to use `Vuex` instead of [`vue-i18n.js`](https://github.com/kazupon/vue-i18n) for internationalization purposes.

I now have the following code block, the purpose of which is to create language states and perform a XMLHttpRequest (for the .json files storing the various translations):

```
Vue.use(Vuex);
var storelang = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        lang: {}
    },
    mutations: {
        LANG: function (state, ln) {
            function loadJSON(callback) {
                var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
                xobj.open('GET', '../resources/i18n/' + ln + '.json', true);
                xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
                        callback(xobj.responseText);
                    }
                };
                xobj.send(null);
            }

            loadJSON(function (languageJSON) {
                state.lang = JSON.parse(languageJSON);
            })
        },
        strict: true
    }
});

var mix = Vue.mixin({
    computed: {
        lang: function () {
        return storelang.state.lang;
        }
    }

});
```

On my `component constructor` (created and initialized in the root Vue instance), I've the following:

```
components: {
        lang: {
            template: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" @click.prevent=activate(lang.code) @click="setActiveLang" v-show="!isActive">{{ lang.code }}</button>',
            props: [
                'active',
                'lang'
            ],
            computed: {
                isActive: function() {
                    return this.lang.code == this.active.code
                }
            },
            methods: {
                activate: function(code) {
                    storelang.dispatch('LANG', code);
                },
                setActiveLang: function() {
                    this.active = this.lang;
                }
            },
            ready: function() {
                storelang.dispatch('LANG', 'en'); //default language
            }
        }
    }
```

On my `root Vue instance's data object`, I've added the following:

```
langs: [{
    code: "en"
}, {
    code: "fr"
}, {
    code: "pt"
}],
active: {
    "code": "pt"
}
```

And finally, on my `html`:

```
<div v-for="lang in langs">
    <p>
        <lang :lang="lang" :active.sync="active"></lang>
    </p>
</div>
```

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

---

**UPDATE**

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/674z6w0h/24/) a JsFiddle (I've exchanged the  XMLHttpRequest request for `json` arrays). Also, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/674z6w0h/23/) is a working example, but the language selector buttons do not hide when the respective language is selected, which is the opposite of what I want. Meaning that, I'm attempting to hide each individual language selector button when the user clicks it and selects the respective language (while showing the other language selector buttons).

Comment: Could you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: I've updated the question with a couple more JsFiddles at the bottom and added further clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution involves saving an`active` state in the `store`, in addition to the `lang` state:

```
new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        active: {},
        lang: {}
```

Adding an `ACTIVE` `mutation`:

```
ACTIVE: function(state, ln) {
        var langcode = 'en'
    //portuguese
    if (ln === 'pt') {
        langcode = 'pt'
    }
    //french
    if (ln === 'fr') {
        langcode = 'fr'
    }
  state.active = langcode
}
```

On the computed properties block, one also needs to add getter functions for the `active` state and return the `langcode` that is currently `active`:

```
Vue.mixin({
    computed: {
        lang: function() {
            return storelang.state.lang
        },
        enIsActive: function() {
            return storelang.state.active == 'en'
        },
        frIsActive: function() {
            return storelang.state.active == 'fr'
        },
        ptIsActive: function() {
            return storelang.state.active == 'pt'
        }
    }
})
```

Then, it is just a question of conditionally displaying each of the buttons on the component template by adding `v-show="!enIsActive"`, `v-show="!frIsActive"`, etc.:

```
var langBtn = Vue.extend({
template: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" @click.prevent=activate("en") v-show="!enIsActive">en</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" @click.prevent=activate("pt") v-show="!ptIsActive">pt</button><button  type="button" class="btn btn-info" @click.prevent=activate("fr") v-show="!frIsActive">fr</button>',
```

Finally, on the `activate` method, adding a new line to change the `active` state when the user clicks a button:

```
methods: {
    activate: function(x) {
      storelang.dispatch('LANG', x)
      storelang.dispatch('ACTIVE', x)
    }
  },
```

The full working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/674z6w0h/29/).